# Using a 2D array to store weather data. c++

Tags: c++, arrays

So im creating a program that would store weather data inside a 2D array and i have everything set up for the most part, i think, but im stuck on actually storing it in the array. This is what i have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  const int days = 7;
  const int temp = 3;

  float averageTemp;
  float highTemp;
  float lowTemp;

  float array1[days][temp];

  for(int i = 0; i < days; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < temp; k++){
      cout << "Enter low temperature: ";
      cin >> lowTemp;
      cout << "Enter average temperature: ";
      cin >> avgTemp;
      cout << "Enter high temperature: ";
      cin >> highTemp;
    }
  }
}
```

so basically i have to store the average, high, and low temperature for the day inside the array

This is how it should look when i print it out:

```
Thursday
Average Temperature: 55
High Temperature: 72
Low Temperature: 45
```

But it has to do it for everyday of the week

I think i have it set up right but now sure how to store these values into the array. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong? Do you know how to store something in an array in general? If so, then what part of storing values here are you struggling with?

Comment: You would need to set `array1[i][k];` to the appropriate value.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, nah, OP has an extra loop, the `[k]` index is a mistake given the three other variables being read into in that loop

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only need an outer loop, otherwise you are asking for the low, average, and high temperatures `temp` times per day. You can address this in a couple of ways

```
for(int i = 0; i < days; i++){
    cout << "Enter low temperature: ";
    cin >> lowTemp;
    cout << "Enter average temperature: ";
    cin >> avgTemp;
    cout << "Enter high temperature: ";
    cin >> highTemp;

    // store everything after reading
    array1[i][0] = lowTemp;
    array1[i][1] = avgTemp;
    array1[i][2] = highTemp;
}
```

Or, you can skip the intermediate variables and read straight into the array

```
for(int i = 0; i < days; i++){
    cout << "Enter low temperature: ";
    cin >> array1[i][0];
    cout << "Enter average temperature: ";
    cin >> array1[i][1];
    cout << "Enter high temperature: ";
    cin >> array1[i][2];
}
```

There are many other improvements I would recommend here, like using a `struct` to hold the three temperatures instead of a 2D array. Other answers give many such recommendations, but it seems like this is a homework assignment to me, and you probably don't have much leeway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this ?

```
 string days[] = {"Monday", "Tuesday"...};

 for(int i = 0; i < days; i++){
      cout << days[i] << '\n';
      cout << "Enter low temperature: ";
      cin >> array1[i][0];
      cout << "Enter average temperature: ";
      cin >> array1[i][1];
      cout << "Enter high temperature: ";
      cin >> array1[i][2];
}
```

Comment: Teach a man to fish, and he'll eat for a lifetime. Give a man a fish, and he'll try to stick it directly into his code without knowing what it does.

Comment: @scohe001 i hope you realize i do know what this code does. the only thing i didnt know is how to store them into the array. im still learning c++ and my code was not that far off from this one, granted i had a unneeded nested for loop

Comment: @ddec that's good that you know what the code is doing in this instance. But the real questions to be asking here are why did you think you needed another loop? How were you debugging and testing and in the future, how can you change that to catch mistakes like this? If you know what all of this code does, why weren't you able to reach this solution yourself? You won't always have StackOverflow to catch things like this for you and just give you the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go for some extra readability:

```
enum Temperature_Indices {TEMP_HIGH, TEMP_AVERAGE, TEMP_LOW, MAX_TEMPS};
enum Day_Name_Indices {SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, MAX_DAYS};
static const char day_names[] =
{ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
  "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

int main()
{
    int temperatures[MAX_DAYS][MAX_TEMPS];
    for(int day = 0; day < MAX_DAYS; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter low temperature: ";
        cin >> temperatures[day][TEMP_LOW];
        cout << "Enter average temperature: ";
        cin >> temperatures[day][TEMP_AVERAGE];
        cout << "Enter high temperature: ";
        cin >> temperatures[day][TEMP_HIGH];
    }
    for(int day = 0; day < MAX_DAYS; i++)
    {
        std::cout << day_names[day] << "\n";
        std::cout << "Low temperature: " << temperatures[day][TEMP_LOW] << "\n";
        std::cout << "Average temperature: " << temperatures[day][TEMP_AVERAGE] << "\n";
        std::cout << "High temperature: " << temperatures[day][TEMP_HIGH] << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the array1[days][temp] has rows 0,1,2,3,... for weeks Mon, tues, wed, thur,...
And columns 0,1,2 for avgtemp, hightemp, and lowtemp.

See this code, you can directly get input using array indices.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int days = 7;
    const int temp = 3;
    float array1[days][temp];
    // getting user input
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n==========\n";
        cout << " WEEK # " << i + 1;
        cout << "\n==========\n\n";

        cout << " Average temperature = ";
        cin >> array1[i][0];

        cout << " High temperature = ";
        cin >> array1[i][1];

        cout << " Low temperature = ";
        cin >> array1[i][2];
    }

    // displaying...
    cout << "\n=============== RESULT ===============\n"
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n==========\n";
        cout << " WEEK # " << i + 1;
        cout << "\n==========\n\n";

        cout << " Average temperature is " << array1[i][0] << endl;
        cout << " High temperature is " << array1[i][1] << endl;
        cout << " Low temperature is " << array1[i][2] << endl;
    }
}
```

You can modify this code to display "Monday" if i == 0, "Tuesday" if i == 1, and so on...
To do that, you can use the function below, and use #include  for it.

```
string numberToWeekName(int num)
{
    if(num == 0){ return "Monday"; }
    if(num == 1){ return "Tuesday"; }
    if(num == 2){ return "Wednesday"; }
    if(num == 3){ return "Thursday"; }
    if(num == 4){ return "Friday"; }
    if(num == 5){ return "Saturday" }
    if(num == 6){ return "Sunday"; }
    return "Nothing";
}
```

You must learn to find other ways as well.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Your input is fragile and likely to leave an element uninitialized on any input matching failure. All user-input should be validated, e.g. `if (!(std::cin >> array1[i][0])) { std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n"; return 1; }`. (or you should at least note that validation of input is required but was omitted from the example...) [10 Commandments for C Programmers - No. 6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html) applies equally well to C++.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that :-) ... I was trying to keep things since it seems like a beginner's question. I hope he figures out that part.